# What determines which local SQL Server cache tables can be cached?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2008, caching

I have a c# Visual Studio app. I connected to an existing SQL Server 2008 database and the Studio created a local cache (.sdf file) for me, caching all existing tables.

Now I added 2 additional tables the the SQL Server database and want to update my DataSet with these, but the wizard does not allow me to select the new tables as being cached. On the "Choose Tables to Cache" wizard page, I cannot check all tables to be cached.

Update: Now it allows me to select one, but not the other of the new tables.

What determines whether tables can be cached? How can I makes this work, with or without the wizard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer.

The "How to: Configure Data Synchronization to Use SQL Server Change Tracking" help page (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc714038.aspx) talks about creating and configuring a Local Database Cache Template (.sync file).

I never saw the template configuration before because the Studio configured this for me automagically. I found the .sync file in Solution Explorer and can open it in the Configure Data Synchronization dialog. When you add a new table to by synchronized here, there is also a link to the "Which tables can be cached" help page (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763049.aspx).